# How to use while loop to creat a dummy variable based on an existing variable?

Tags: r, loops, statistics, dummy-variable, generate

I have a categorical variable called "X1" and a dummy variable called "X2". Now I want to create a dummy variable X3 in a way that follows this logic:

If in any rows of any categories of X1, at least one row gets X2=1, then put X3=1 for all the rows of that category, otherwise 0.

```
X1<-c(1,1,2,2,,3,3)
X2<-c(0,1,0,0,1,1)
```

The desired output I am looking for is like this:

```
X1 X2  X3
 1  0   1
 1  1   1
 2  0   0
 2  0   0
 3  1   1
 3  1   1
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you committed to using a `while` loop or would answers without loops be welcome?

Comment: @GregorThomas Im a newbie in R, Im doing a simulation study so if other answers works in simulation studies, I am super open to any. But the important thing is that I can not force X3 to get any values, because the values of X1, X2 are subject to change

Comment: does this do the trick: `df$x3<-ifelse(df$X1==1 | df$X2==1, 1, 0)`  ?

Comment: @D.J that ignores the grouping by `X1`. If there was an additional row in OPs example with `X1 = 3` and `X2 = 0`, the result should be `X3 = 1`, but your method would give 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
df = data.frame(
  X1 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
  X2 = c(0,1,0,0,1,1)
)


library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(X1) %>%
  mutate(X3 = ifelse(1 %in% X2, 1, 0))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   X1 [3]
#      X1    X2    X3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     0     1
# 2     1     1     1
# 3     2     0     0
# 4     2     0     0
# 5     3     1     1
# 6     3     1     1
```

Here's the same idea in base R:

```
df$X3 = with(df, ave(X2, X1, FUN = function(x) ifelse(1 %in% x, 1, 0)))
df
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  0  1
# 2  1  1  1
# 3  2  0  0
# 4  2  0  0
# 5  3  1  1
# 6  3  1  1
```

Comment: Many thanks! Just a quick Q on the first command, I tried to run it but it didn't show X3, is it because of the %>% sign? I mean should I remove them? (It was like I put the # next to the command)

Comment: No, the `%>%` should be kept in.  I didn't assign the result, so it would print but not change your data. If you put `df <-` at the start, so `df <- df %>% group_by...` it will modify the data frame.

Comment: I can't vote but everyone knows! I give him 10/10! Thanks Gregor! :)

Comment: I was trying to multiply X3 to another binary V. I have, but it gave this error: "non-numeric argument to binary operator" as I was writing a function. Does this mean the type of X3 we get here, has to be changed? I was looking for a way to change it inside the command but it turned out there is no such a thing

Comment: In my answer `X3` is numeric. Check your classes to make sure - what is `class(df$X3)`, what is `class(V)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `max` value of `X2` in each group (`X1`).

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(X1) %>% mutate(X3 = max(X2)) %>% ungroup

#     X1    X2    X3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0     1
#2     1     1     1
#3     2     0     0
#4     2     0     0
#5     3     1     1
#6     3     1     1
```

In base R and `data.table` :

```
#Base R
transform(df, X3 = ave(X2, X1, FUN = max))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, X3 := max(X2), X1]
```

**data**

```
X1<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
X2<-c(0,1,0,0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(X1, X2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
ftransform(df, X3 = fmax(X2, X1, TRA = 'replace_fill'))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), X2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```